# Strangeness on farm after Feb 2012 CU

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, patching

Over the weekend I took my production server from SP1 to the Feb 2012 CU - I performed the upgrade about a month earlier on my development environment and didn't notice any issues.

On my production environment I have 4 servers (2 x APP, 2 x WFE), I stopped the User Profile Service and ran the update on the 1st APP server, once this finished I ran the Update on APP2, then the WFEs. Once the update completed each of the boxes were rebooted (the update recommended this).

I then ran the Products and configuration wizard on the servers in the same order. On APP1 it failed, APP2 it failed but was successful on the two WFE servers, after I went back to the APP servers and re-ran it was successful.

I started the User Profile and ran Central Admin, everything was looking good.

Now, a few days later and I've noticed the following:

- When you go to pages which contain data view web parts intermittently I get "The web part could not be displayed"
- When you select an item using the arrow, and go to edit, an error occurs
- some lists do't contain the full URL in the "All Items" view - however the list is there and works

Has anyone else experienced things like this either in the past or with this update - perhaps I should have installed the Foundation patches as well as the server patches? Any recommendations on troubleshooting and fixing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try narrowing down the issue to a single WFE, setup AAM to each server name and browse on each server. See if one is giving more issues vs the other? Check logs on all servers

Comment: the issue was resolved as the failing web parts were dure to the timeout setting introduced in an earlier CU; setting the dataview timeout back to 5 secs resolved this.

Comment: Could you check your farms upgrade status? Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Check Upgrade Status (should be "Succeeded"). Also check Database status: Review Database Status (should be "No action required")

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you for sure that i've experience the exact same behavior for the following:

- had to run twice the Configuration Wizard on APP machines for it to be succesfull
- had to manually start UPSA and even Search

You do not need to run Foundation updates anymore (Cumulative Updates for Servers have it all), same applies to Language packs too. I didn't however experienced the the problems you have. Did you checked the ULS logs, Event logs? Did you checked in Patching Level on each of the machines - are they reporting anything. Also, just to sure that services started prior on the each machine are again running properly.
,
For more troubleshooting try using ULS Viewer while you attempt accessing the lists on your Web Front Ends (if it doesn't disrupt too much, you could remove one WFE from your farm to ease on troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the first point:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2012/03/07/xslt-and-timeout-problem-when-transforming-runs-more-than-one-second.aspx

Comment: Please dont just add links out of this site. These external links tend to die, so we want the solution to appear here in the answer please (and then link).